# Horizontal background image position on vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, frontend

I am deemed with the task to mimic the scrolling sections on this demo. http://sandbox.linkrightmedia.com/acme-home/

My current build is at http://demo.acmeroofsystems.com/.

I cannot seem to figure it out after many different methods of action.

The goal is to move the background images of each section, minimally, while scrolling vertically.  I would prefer to only trigger this while the section is in anywhere in view of the window, so as to minimize the event triggering.

So far, I have come up with just a bit of code, but it does not work.

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {

    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

var $services = $('#front-services'),
    windowWidth = window.outerWidth;

if ( windowWidth >= 768) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
        if (isScrolledIntoView($services)) {
            console.log(currentScrollPosition)
        }
    });
}
```

The goal is to only trigger this also while on tablets or higher (after 768px).  I am merely testing right now, but would eventually like to replace the `console.log` statement with a `background-position-y` adjustment that moves it like 1/10 pixel horizontally for each 1px vertically scrolled.

But I cannot even get it to trigger correctly to even get some numbers to work with for editing the background position.  How can this be achieved?